# Python Else statement is voided

Tags: python, python-3.x

When user input is anything different from the specified letters "A", "a", "B", "b", "C", "c", "E", "e", it doesn't run the `else` statement but just closes. I would also like to have it repeat the program again if user input is not any of the specified letters, how can I achieve that? I believe it would be something I'd have to add in the else statement.

```py
user_input = input()

if user_input in ("A", "a", "B", "b", "C", "c", "E", "e"):

    if user_input == "A" or user_input == "a":
        print("You chose A")

    elif user_input == "B" or user_input == "b":
        print("You chose B")

    elif user_input == "C" or user_input == "c":
        print("You chose C")

    elif user_input == "E" or user_input == "e":
        print("You chose to exit the program")

    else:
        print("Something went wrong, try again")
```

Comment: That is because of the indentation of the last else - it is nested within the first if.

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` should be part of the outer `if` (so same indentation), for now it is part of the inner `if`

Also you can simplify the tests, by first using `.upper()` to deal only with uppercase letters, and test the inclusion with `user_input in "ABCDE"`

```
user_input = input().upper()
if user_input in "ABCDE":
    if user_input == "A":
        print("You chose A")
    elif user_input == "B":
        print("You chose B")
    elif user_input == "C":
        print("You chose C")
    elif user_input == "E":
        print("You chose to exit the program")
else:
    print("Something went wrong, try again")
```

---

#### Ask again version

```
user_input = input("Please choose: ").upper()

while user_input not in "ABCDE":
    print("Something went wrong, try again: ")
    user_input = input().upper()

if user_input == "A":
    print("You chose A")
elif user_input == "B":
    print("You chose B")
elif user_input == "C":
    print("You chose C")
elif user_input == "E":
    print("You chose to exit the program")
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue! Any advice on how to repeat the code to first line if it gets to the else statement?

Comment: @verycool just add it. You can accept the answer if it satisfies you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Python is very indentation specific. This should do the trick:

```
user_input = input()
if user_input in ("A", "a", "B", "b", "C", "c", "E", "e"):

    if user_input == "A" or user_input == "a":
        print("You chose A")

    elif user_input == "B" or user_input == "b":
        print("You chose B")

    elif user_input == "C" or user_input == "c":
        print("You chose C")

    elif user_input == "E" or user_input == "e":
        print("You chose to exit the program")
else:
    print("Something went wrong, try again")
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't compile BECAUSE of your indentation, check that :D

Comment: Your username is even cooler. :)